# I have a question about english grammar

Tags: phrase-usage

please look at the sentence:

> I **go through** the course prescribed for surgeon in army.

What does **go through** mean here and can you explain ' course prescribed for .....' for me?

Answer (score 3):

> *I* go through the course prescribed for *a* surgeon in *the* army.

*go through* means to participate in (and hopefully complete) a series of classes/activities (the *course*) that must be completed to become skilled in some profession.

[***prescribe***](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/prescribe) as used here means:

> 4) to set down or impose rules; dictate

so in your example it refers to those rules and requirements that are specified for persons in that occupation.